# How to wrap a row of texts?

Tags: flutter

I have two Text widgets inside a Row. I want to show the text widgets one after another, and wrap the second one to the next line if it doesn't fit in the first line.

I've tried Flexible, Wrap, and what not. I can't seem to get it working.

```dart
Row(
    children: <Widget>[
        Text('This is some text.'),
        Text('Another piece of text.')
    ]
);
```

I want the output to look something like this (the screen edges are indicated by |):

```
|This is some text. Another |
|piece of text.             |
```

The best I could get was the following:

```
|This is some  Another piece|
|text.         of text.     |
```

**Edit**: Thanks for replies, everyone. I've tried RichText too, and it works, but I want to bind more than one gesture to each TextSpan element, which cannot be done easily with RichText. I'm about to create a question on that, but stackoverflow doesn't allow me to create more than one question in 90 minutes.

Comment: Add this:

    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween

Comment: @MaadhavSharma, that didn't work. If it's working for you, can you share your code?

Comment: please post your code, how you have implemented.

Comment: use [Rich text class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/RichText-class.html)

Comment: @MaadhavSharma, I added `mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween` as the first argument to `Row` above.

Answer (score 1):

The [Wrap Widget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Wrap-class.html) will either keep the two Texts on the same line or put the second Text on the next line if there's overflow.

```
Wrap(
  children: [
    Text(
      'This is some text.',
    ),
    Text(
      'Another piece of text.',
    ),
  ],
),
```

Comment: I'm getting the following error: "Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget. Expanded widgets must be placed inside Flex widgets...". Can you share your code in full?

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATED ANSWER**

The first thing you are doing wrong is using Row to put one text widget under another text.

`|This is some text. Another |
 |piece of text.             |`

This is the desired UI are you are trying to achieve right? So From your question, it is clear that you want two text widget one under another.

so this code will work for you. replace `Row` with `Column` widget like this. If you want to continue with Row each of your text will wrap but not one text after another. here is the working code. I have putted two text to show you that how they wrap one after another. Checkout the image below to see the result

```
body: Center(
    child: Container(
      color: Colors.amberAccent,
      width: 200,
      height: 200,
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Flexible(
              fit: FlexFit.tight,
              child: Text(
                'This is some text.long text more long Text, even more long text',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20.0),
              ),
            ),
            Flexible(
              fit: FlexFit.tight,
              child: Text(
                'Another piece of text.not so long text yet needs to be a liitle long text',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20.0),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
```

here is the screenshot [image]

Comment: Thanks, but your suggestion didn't work. I get the texts on two lines. I want to continue the first line and only wrap the text to the next line if it doesn't fit the screen. In your screenshot, I'd expect 'A' to appear after 'Fruid Salad' on the same row. And the next row should continue with 'refreshing...'.

Comment: @PuchkaIndur, thanks for the update, but that's not what I want. See how 'Another' in my original question is on the same line as the first text. In your example, both texts are on separate lines.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that using the RichText widget:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
    appBar: AppBar(),
    body: RichText(
      text: TextSpan(
        children: [
          TextSpan(text: "This is some text."),
          TextSpan(text: "Another piece of text. Another piece of text. Another piece of text. Another piece of text."),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

> The RichText widget displays text that uses multiple different styles.
>   The text to display is described using a tree of TextSpan objects,
>   each of which has an associated style that is used for that subtree.
>   **The text might break across multiple lines** or might all be displayed
>   on the same line depending on the layout constraints.

[RichText](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/RichText-class.html)

Comment: Thanks. I forgot to mention that I tried using RichText, and although it works, I couldn't bind more than one gesture to TextSpan, which only accepts one gesture recognizer. How can I achieve the above using Text widgets?

Comment: You can add any of the gestures of one type recognizer, for example you could add onTapUp, onTapDown and onTapCancel from the TapGestureRecognizer to a TextSpan, or you can add onDown, onStart, onEnd, onUpdate and onCancel from DragGestureRecognizer, but if you want to add onTapUp and onStart to the same TextSpan, I think it's not possible, is that what you want?

Comment: Yes, I want to add onTap and onLongPress, which seems impossible?

Comment: Doesn't seems to be possible, it would be interesting to post a specific question for that. But I have a workaround for your case, you could simulate a long press using the onTapDown and onTapUp using a Timer

Comment: I posted it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58342982/how-to-add-multiple-gesture-recognizers-to-textspan