# How to add multiple gesture recognizers to TextSpan?

Tags: flutter

I'd like to add both a TapGestureRecognizer and a LongPressGestureRecognizer to a [TextSpan](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/TextSpan-class.html). Right now I can add either one, but not both.

I've looked into the GestureDetector class and wanted to wrap TextSpan with it, but the RichText element only accepts TextSpans and not Widgets.

This is what I have now:

```
TextSpan(
    text: "some text",
    recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer()
    ..onTap = () { print('tapped'); }
)
```

And I want to add `..onLongPress` somewhere in that code.

At the end both gestures should work on the single text span.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It doesn't seem to be possible to add more than one GestureRecognizer to a TextSpan, but here is a workaround for your case with just the TapGestureRecognizer and using the onTapUp and onTapDown to detect a tap and to simulate a long tap, using a Timer:

```
TapGestureRecognizer _tapGestureRecognizer;
Timer _timer;

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  _initRecognizer();
}

_initRecognizer() {
  _tapGestureRecognizer = TapGestureRecognizer();
  _tapGestureRecognizer.onTapUp = (_) {
    if (_timer != null && _timer.isActive) {
      print('Tap');
      _timer.cancel();
    }
  };
  _tapGestureRecognizer.onTapDown = (_) {
    _timer = Timer(Duration(seconds: 1), () {
      print('Long Tap');
    });
  };
}

@override
void dispose() {
  if (_timer != null) {
    _timer.cancel();
    _timer = null;
  }
  super.dispose();
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
    appBar: AppBar(),
    body: Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
      child: RichText(
        text: TextSpan(
          children: [
            TextSpan(
              text: "This is some text.",
              recognizer: _tapGestureRecognizer,
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.title,
            ),
            TextSpan(
              text:
              "Another piece of text. Another piece of text. Another piece of text. Another piece of text.",
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.title,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use **WidgetSpan** to set into your span and detect TapGestureRecognizer and LongPressGestureRecognizer by GestureDetector

```
 TextSpan(
          children: <InlineSpan>[
            TextSpan(text: 'Flutter is'),
            WidgetSpan(
                child: GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {
                    
                  },
                  onLongPress: () {
                    
                  },
                  child: Text(' Hello World! '),
                )
            ),
            TextSpan(text: 'the best!'),
          ],
        )
```

Answer (score 1):

I combined `TapGestureRecognizer` and `LongPressGestureRecognizer` into a simple `TapAndLongPressGestureRecognizer`:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart';

///
/// A simple [GestureRecognizer] that combines [TapGestureRecognizer] and [LongPressGestureRecognizer]
/// It only supports two simple callbacks [onTap] and [onLongPress]
///
class TapAndLongPressGestureRecognizer extends PrimaryPointerGestureRecognizer {
  /// Creates a gesture recognizer.
  TapAndLongPressGestureRecognizer({
    Duration? duration,
    double? postAcceptSlopTolerance,
    @Deprecated(
      'Migrate to supportedDevices. '
      'This feature was deprecated after v2.3.0-1.0.pre.',
    )
        PointerDeviceKind? kind,
    Set<PointerDeviceKind>? supportedDevices,
    Object? debugOwner,
  }) : super(
          deadline: duration ?? kLongPressTimeout,
          postAcceptSlopTolerance: postAcceptSlopTolerance,
          kind: kind,
          supportedDevices: supportedDevices,
          debugOwner: debugOwner,
        );

  bool _longPressAccepted = false;
  // The buttons sent by `PointerDownEvent`. If a `PointerMoveEvent` comes with a
  // different set of buttons, the gesture is canceled.
  int? _initialButtons;

  bool _sentTapDown = false;
  bool _wonArenaForPrimaryPointer = false;

  PointerDownEvent? _down;
  PointerUpEvent? _up;

  /// Called when a long press gesture by a primary button has been recognized.
  ///
  GestureLongPressCallback? onLongPress;

  /// A pointer has stopped contacting the screen, which is recognized as a tap
  /// of a primary button.
  ///
  /// This triggers on the up event, if the recognizer wins the arena with it
  /// or has previously won, immediately following [onTapUp].
  ///
  GestureTapCallback? onTap;

  VelocityTracker? _velocityTracker;

  @override
  bool isPointerAllowed(PointerDownEvent event) {
    switch (event.buttons) {
      case kPrimaryButton:
        if (onLongPress == null) {
          return false;
        }
        break;
      default:
        return false;
    }
    return super.isPointerAllowed(event);
  }

  @override
  void addAllowedPointer(PointerDownEvent event) {
    assert(event != null);
    if (state == GestureRecognizerState.ready) {
      // If there is no result in the previous gesture arena,
      // we ignore them and prepare to accept a new pointer.
      if (_down != null && _up != null) {
        assert(_down!.pointer == _up!.pointer);
        _resetTap();
      }

      assert(_down == null && _up == null);
      // `_down` must be assigned in this method instead of `handlePrimaryPointer`,
      // because `acceptGesture` might be called before `handlePrimaryPointer`,
      // which relies on `_down` to call `handleTapDown`.
      _down = event;
    }
    if (_down != null) {
      // This happens when this tap gesture has been rejected while the pointer
      // is down (i.e. due to movement), when another allowed pointer is added,
      // in which case all pointers are simply ignored. The `_down` being null
      // means that _reset() has been called, since it is always set at the
      // first allowed down event and will not be cleared except for reset(),
      super.addAllowedPointer(event);
    }
  }

  @override
  void didExceedDeadline() {
    // Exceeding the deadline puts the gesture in the accepted state.
    resolve(GestureDisposition.accepted);
    _longPressAccepted = true;
    super.acceptGesture(primaryPointer!);
    _checkLongPressStart();
  }

  @override
  void handlePrimaryPointer(PointerEvent event) {
    if (!event.synthesized) {
      if (event is PointerDownEvent) {
        _velocityTracker = VelocityTracker.withKind(event.kind);
        _velocityTracker!.addPosition(event.timeStamp, event.localPosition);
      }
      if (event is PointerMoveEvent) {
        assert(_velocityTracker != null);
        _velocityTracker!.addPosition(event.timeStamp, event.localPosition);
      }
    }

    if (event is PointerUpEvent) {
      if (_longPressAccepted == true) {
        _checkLongPressEnd(event);
        _resetTap();
      } else {
        _up = event;
        _checkTapUp();
      }
      _resetLongPress();
    } else if (event is PointerCancelEvent) {
      _resetLongPress();
      if (_sentTapDown) {
        _checkTapCancel(event, '');
      }
      _resetTap();
    } else if (event is PointerDownEvent) {
      _initialButtons = event.buttons;
      _down = event;
      _checkTapDown();
    } else if (event is PointerMoveEvent) {
      if (event.buttons != _initialButtons) {
        resolve(GestureDisposition.rejected);
        stopTrackingPointer(primaryPointer!);
      }
    }
  }

  void _checkTapUp() {
    if (!_wonArenaForPrimaryPointer || _up == null) {
      return;
    }
    assert(_up!.pointer == _down!.pointer);
    switch (_down!.buttons) {
      case kPrimaryButton:
        if (onTap != null) {
          invokeCallback<void>('onTap', onTap!);
        }
        break;
      default:
    }
    _resetTap();
  }

  void _checkTapDown() {
    if (_sentTapDown) {
      return;
    }
    _sentTapDown = true;
  }

  void _checkTapCancel(PointerCancelEvent? event, String note) {}

  void _resetTap() {
    _sentTapDown = false;
    _wonArenaForPrimaryPointer = false;
    _up = null;
    _down = null;
  }

  void _checkLongPressStart() {
    switch (_initialButtons) {
      case kPrimaryButton:
        if (onLongPress != null) {
          invokeCallback<void>('onLongPress', onLongPress!);
        }
        break;
      default:
        assert(false, 'Unhandled button $_initialButtons');
    }
  }

  void _checkLongPressEnd(PointerEvent event) {
    _velocityTracker = null;
  }

  void _resetLongPress() {
    _longPressAccepted = false;
    _initialButtons = null;
    _velocityTracker = null;
  }

  @override
  void resolve(GestureDisposition disposition) {
    if (disposition == GestureDisposition.rejected) {
      if (_longPressAccepted) {
        // This can happen if the gesture has been canceled. For example when
        // the buttons have changed.
        _resetLongPress();
      }

      if (_wonArenaForPrimaryPointer && _sentTapDown) {
        // This can happen if the gesture has been canceled. For example, when
        // the pointer has exceeded the touch slop, the buttons have been changed,
        // or if the recognizer is disposed.
        _checkTapCancel(null, 'spontaneous');
        _resetTap();
      }
    }
    super.resolve(disposition);
  }

  @override
  void acceptGesture(int pointer) {
    if (pointer == primaryPointer && _down != null) {
      _checkTapDown();
      _wonArenaForPrimaryPointer = true;
      _checkTapUp();
    }
  }

  @override
  void rejectGesture(int pointer) {
    super.rejectGesture(pointer);
    if (pointer == primaryPointer) {
      // Another gesture won the arena.
      assert(state != GestureRecognizerState.possible);
      if (_sentTapDown) {
        _checkTapCancel(null, 'forced');
      }
      _resetTap();
    }
  }

  @override
  String get debugDescription => 'tap or long press';
}
```

Comment: with latest version of flutter  it produces error of TapAndLongPressGestureRecognizer is not supported.
'package:flutter/src/rendering/paragraph.dart':
paragraph.dart:1
Failed assertion: line 1195 pos 20: 'false' . Can you please update the answer that works with latest version.

Answer (score 0):

A trick I found for this problem is to use `LongPressGestureRecognizer` and use `onLongPressCancel` method as Tap action and `OnLongPress` for Long press action.